# what jquery event should i use for this type of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project(back-end) and the front-end programmer wrote the dropdown code like this

```
<div class="drop-wrap drop-wrap-s-4 color-4 list-sort order-drop">
    <div class="drop">
        <b>Sort by price</b>
        <a href="#" class="drop-list"><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
       <span>
         <a href="#" class="order">Cheapest</a>
         <a href="#" class="order">Most Expensive</a>
       </span>
     </div>
</div>
```

How do i get the selected value? what event will i use on the javascript side for ajax call?

I tried something ike this

```
$(".order-drop").onselect(function () {
        var order= $("a.order").val();
});
```

and this

```
$(".order-drop").onchange(function () {
        var order= $("a.order").val();
});
```

Comment: That is not a dropdown, it may look like a dropdown on front end but is not a dropdown.

Comment: A div does not have the onchange or onselect event, they only have mouse and keyboard events. What you need is a select element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's not a regular dropdown/select element, there won't be any change events.

To get the text of the selected item, add an event handler to the link elements like this...

```
$(".order-drop .order").on("click", function() {

    // here you can get the text of the selected item...
    console.log(this.textContent);

});
```

That will attach the click handler to each of the elements with the class `order` inside any element with the class `order-drop`.  This may or may not be suitable, depending on what else is on the page.  Any other elements that fit that selector will also be targeted by this code, so watch out for that.